# Как переопределить маршрут в Identity. Asp.net core.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Я создал готовый (individual account), мне там предоставили: готовая автризация, регистрация, и личный кабинет. 
 Но, подскажите как мне в них переопределить маршруты(Route), чтобы к примеру при регистрации Было в адрессной строке **не**: `/Identity/Account/Register`, a `/Account/Register`. Интересует, как это можно сделать максимально просто, чтобы контроллеры все не переписывать
Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: в asp.net-mvc это можно сделать при помощи атрибутов маршрутизации

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL-k0Ff5RfqXnwdDG61WqZ2j3KXUPnfmq&disable_polymer=true  
уроки 37 , 38 , 39 , 40

Comment: Так уроки ведь по MVC, а не Core. Знаю что там достаточно много отличий, не считая разве что структуру mvc.

Answer (score 0):

В Startup.cs есть метод Configure. Там можно переопределить маршрут:

```
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "goto_one",
                template: "one",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" });
         });
```

Comment: не работает, не знаю почему. Все также переходит на Identity

Comment: можно где-то скачать Ваш код?

Comment: asp.net core 2.1 mvc- individual account. Ничего особо не менял

Comment: аттрибут [Route("")]  изменить пробывали?

Comment: А где конкретно менять надо? Пробывал в модели RegisterModel - не получается. Контроллеров созданных нет

Comment: В контроллере сверху атрибут  [Route(""путь/к контроллеру"")]